# Create custom Serializer and Deserializer in kafka using scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, gson

I am using kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1 and scala_2.10.3.
I want to write custom Serializer and Deserializer using scala.
I tried with these Serializer (from CustomType) and Deserializer (obtain a CustomType):

```
  class CustomTypeSerializer extends Serializer[CustomType] {
    private val gson: Gson = new Gson()

    override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean):
    Unit = {
      // nothing to do
    }

    override def serialize(topic: String, data: CustomType): Array[Byte] = {
      if (data == null)
        null
      else
        gson.toJson(data).getBytes
    }

    override def close(): Unit = {
      //nothing to do
    }
  }

  class CustomTypeDeserializer extends Deserializer[CustomType] {
    private val gson: Gson = new Gson()

    override def deserialize(topic: String, bytes: Array[Byte]): CustomType = {
      val offerJson = gson.toJson(bytes.toString)
      val psType: Type = new TypeToken[CustomType]() {}.getType()
      val ps: CustomType = gson.fromJson(offerJson, psType)
      ps
    }

    override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean):
    Unit = {
      // nothing to do
    }

    override def close(): Unit = {
      //nothing to do
    }
  }
```

But, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition topic_0_1-1 at offset 26
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
at kafka.PSDeserializer.deserialize(PSDeserializer.scala:24)
at kafka.PSDeserializer.deserialize(PSDeserializer.scala:18)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:627)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseFetchedData(Fetcher.java:548)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:354)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1000)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
```

Can you help me please

Comment: What have you tried? What are your requirements? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I found java examples but not in scala.  If you are aware of writing an example using scala, please do share

Comment: Your deserializer is expecting an Object but the message is an Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find below the custom serializer and deserializer for case class User, User(name:String,id:Int). Replace User in code with your case class. It will work.

```
import java.io.{ObjectInputStream, ByteArrayInputStream}
import java.util

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{Deserializer, Serializer}

class CustomDeserializer extends Deserializer[User]{

  override def configure(configs: util.Map[String,_],isKey: Boolean):Unit = {

  }
  override def deserialize(topic:String,bytes: Array[Byte]) = {
    val byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn)
    val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[User]
    byteIn.close()
    objIn.close()
    obj
  }
  override def close():Unit = {

  }

}

import java.io.{ObjectOutputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream}
import java.util
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer


class CustomSerializer extends Serializer[User]{

  override def configure(configs: util.Map[String,_],isKey: Boolean):Unit = {

  }


  override def serialize(topic:String, data:User):Array[Byte] = {
    try {
      val byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut)
      objOut.writeObject(data)
      objOut.close()
      byteOut.close()
      byteOut.toByteArray
    }
    catch {
      case ex:Exception => throw new Exception(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }

  override def close():Unit = {

  }


}
```

Comment: @Mahesh Chand Kandpal : getting error Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh I cannot help you until you will share your code. Ask the question and give me the URL of the question.